Getting error "Contract-transaction-hash="" does not match provided contract-tx-hash=""
I have been using the protocol kit for creating, proposing and executing the transaction via backend. I'm still able to process the transaction for Matic and ZED token, but USDT doesn't seem to work. This is the token_address for USDT used - 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F
Anyone else facing the issue? Any help would be much appreciated.
These are the packages used -
"@safe-global/api-kit": "^2.2.0",
"@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^3.0.1",
"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^4.0.1",

Error: Contract-transaction-hash=0x9fcf67fd508eb2d48291193e8ffd95f6945a3eb04802667e69756b48f78949d6 does not match provided contract-tx-hash=0x7a4f7b42219a33989f76ed081feb8482382b10673752edec99c5515474539701
    at sendRequest (node_modules/@safe-global/api-kit/dist/src/utils/httpRequests.js:45:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async TransactionHandler.withdrawFromSafe (dist/helpers/transaction_helper.js:122:9)
    at async create_beneficiary (dist/views/transactions/index.js:19:13) {stack: 'Error: Contract-transaction-hash=0x9fcf67fd50dist/views/transactions/index.js:19:13)', message: 'Contract-transaction-hash=0x9fcf67fd508eb2d4…ed081feb8482382b10673752edec99c5515474539701'}
    ```


I faced the same your problem. For me this is because chainId was not correct. So let check to make sure every transaction information are correct, chainId, amount format, address need to is be a checksum address
